# c++ how to assign NULL value to a member pointer when creating new struct

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I'm writing a Run-length encoding project using linked list. Is it possible `next` to have value `NULL` every time i create a `Node` using `new`?

I have

```
struct Node{
    int x;
    char c;
    Node* next;
}
```

and

```
class RLElist{
private:
    Node* startList;
public:
    /*some member functions here*/
}
```

I need it to be `NULL` so i can check if I've reached the last `Node` of the list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are different options:

Add a constructor that value-initializes the pointer (which leaves it zero-initialized):

```
struct Node{
    Node() : next() {}  // you can also value initialize x and c if required.
    int x;
    char c;
    Node* next;
};
```

Initialize at the point of declaration:

```
struct Node{
    int x;
    char c;
    Node* next = nullptr;
};
```

Value-initialize the `new`ed object:

```
node* Node = new Node(); // or new Node{};
```

Comment: if there is no user defined constructor in structure even simple new() will do the thing

Comment: @bits_international yes, these three options are orthogonal.

Comment: One more way, one can declare a static instance, which is zero-initialized by default, call that `null_node`, then create new dynamic instance as `new Node( node_node )` (copying the null-node). Or one can define custom allocation function, relying on the in-practice fact that a nullpointer is all bits zero (on extant computer systems). Or, one can use `cmalloc`, which of course is inadvisable, but it's there. I like for everything to be an odd number so it would be nice with a 7th major way but my idea gen circuit sort of stopped there. So.

Comment: Thank you all for the swift and comprehensive answers!

Answer (score 5):

Yes. And as usual with something that is possible, in this case too there is more than single way to do it.

---

If you call a `new` operator with [value initilization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) semantics

```
Node* n = new Node();
```

than value initialization will be triggered and this will assign 0 value to each structure's data member if there is no user defined constructor in the structure.

---

You can also define a default constructor that will assign null to pointer ( and maybe do something else as well)

```
struct Node{
    int x;
    char c;
    Node* next;
    Node() : next( 0) {}
}
```

and use this as before

```
Node* n = new Node();  // your constructor will be called
```

---

And finally, you can initialize pointer in the place of it's declaration

```
struct Node{
    int x;
    char c;
    Node* next = nullptr;
};
```

Comment: I am at your service sir